# In Jenkins Pipelines, how can the console output from multiple nodes be filtered

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When running jobs in a Jenkins Pipeline in parallel (multi node setup) with the `parallel` keyword, the output of the individual nodes is interleaved. An example output is shown below. Is it possible to filter it so that only the console output of a single node is shown without having to dig through the pipeline steps?

```
[1] Running on BD_SLED12_x86_64-01 in /tmp/jenkins/workspace/ScOSA/continuous/ScOSA_System
[Pipeline] [2] node
[2] Running on SC-010142L in /localdata1/jenkins/workspace/ScOSA/continuous/ScOSA_System@2
[Pipeline] [3] node
[3] Running on SC-010142L in /localdata1/jenkins/workspace/ScOSA/continuous/ScOSA_System@3
[Pipeline] [4] node
[4] Running on SC-010142L in /localdata1/jenkins/workspace/ScOSA/continuous/ScOSA_System@4
[Pipeline] [1] {
[Pipeline] [2] {
[Pipeline] [3] {
[Pipeline] [4] {
[Pipeline] [1] stage
[Pipeline] [1] { (Checkout on BD_SLED12_x86_64-01)
[Pipeline] [2] stage
[Pipeline] [2] { (Checkout on SC-010142L)
[Pipeline] [3] stage
[Pipeline] [3] { (Checkout on SC-010142L)
[Pipeline] [4] stage
[Pipeline] [4] { (Checkout on SC-010142L)
[Pipeline] [1] checkout
[Pipeline] [2] checkout
[Pipeline] [3] checkout
[Pipeline] [4] checkout
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the traditional Jenkins UI, only with [BlueOcean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/). This then looks as follows ([source](https://chef-ci.typo3.org/blue/organizations/jenkins/TYPO3-cookbooks%2Fsite-reviewtypo3org/detail/master/90/pipeline/55)):

[image]